# laravel migration SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I cannot run my migration command due to this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
> constraint (SQL: alter table `user_schools` add constraint
> `user_schools_school_id_foreign` foreign key (`school_id`) references
> `schools` (`id`) on delete cascade)

## Code

`users`

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);
        $table->timestamps();
 });
```

`schools`

```
Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('code')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->set('type', ['TK', 'SD', 'SMP', 'SMA', 'SMK']);
        $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

`user_schools`

```
Schema::create('user_schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->foreignId('school_id')->constrained('schools')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->set('type', ['Manager', 'Staff', 'Teacher', 'Student']);
        $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

> NOTE: My migration files are based on [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) yet I'm getting this error.

**Any idea?**

Comment: `$table->id();` also make your `id` unique,  `primary` and `auro_increament`, they why  you are using `$table->uuid('id')->primary();` instead of that? [Your foreign key belongs wuth this `is` ]

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden screenshot https://ibb.co/mD77vFB

Comment: @TalhaF. uuid is unique and doesn't have to be auto increment it's random string

Comment: You can try with `$table->id();`  hope the problem will gone

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Yes, Yes (Mysql)

Comment: You can use `UUID`s as your Eloquent models’ `ID`. In your Model you need to set the `$keyType` property to `string`, and then `$incrementing` to `false`. You’ll also need to set `$primaryKey` if you call your `primary key` column something other than `id`. Finally, hook into your model’s creating method to generate a `UUID`

Comment: @TalhaF. I've done all that, and model codes are useful for crud purpose I am stuck in creating tables (1 step before crud).

Comment: @TalhaF. it works if i use `$table->id();` but i need my ids to be `uuid`

Comment: I think the problem is that your primary keys are uuid's but your foreign keys are bigIntegers, you need to change `foreignId('user_id')` to `uuid('user_id')` so the foreign key and primary key column types match.

Comment: @Remul how do i change it to foreign uuid?

Comment: Changing `foreignId('user_id')` to `uuid('user_id')` should be enough

Comment: @Remul Life saver :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the types for your primary and foreign key columns don't match.

Your primary key columns are `UUID` and your foreign key columns are `BIGINT`.

Changing the following should solve the error:

```
$table->foreignId('school_id')->constrained('schools')->onDelete('cascade');
```

to

```
$table->uuid('school_id')->constrained('schools')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: The `foreignId` method is an alias for `unsignedBigInteger`, while `uuid` is not an `integer` nor `unsigned` value. Anyway, it`s really helpful